# How to fix Notice (8): Undefined variable: books [APP/Template\books\index.ctp, line 6] in cakePHP?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm totally a new guy in using CakePhp. I have solved some of my problems, yet I'm stock again with this basic problem. Can you help me fix this.

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: books [APP/Template\books\index.ctp, line 6]
Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP/Template\books\index.ctp, line 6]
```

Here's my code where the Error Message is pointing out:

```
<table>
<thead>
<th>ISBN</th><th>Title</th><th>Author</th>
</thead>
<?php foreach($books as $book): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $book['books']['isbn'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book['books']['title'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book['authors']['name'] ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Here's my BooksController.php:

```
<?php
 /**
 * @property BooksController $BooksController
 */
 namespace App\Controller;
 use App\Controller\AppController;
 class BooksController extends AppController {
  public function display()
  {
    function index() {
        $this->books->recursive = 1;
        $books = $this->books->find('all');
        $this->set('books', $books);
    }
    $this->render('index');
  }
 }
 ?>
```

Here's my books.php:

```
<?php
 /**
 * @property books $books
 */

  class books extends AppModel
  {  
    var $name = 'books';
    var $belongsTo = 'authors';
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: where are you defining the variable `books`?

Comment: At the BooksController...

Comment: I'll edit the question to put the BooksController.php

Comment: why is the `index` function inside the `display`?

Comment: also are you calling the display `method` or `index`?

Comment: Because if I don't, the error becomes worst.

Comment: Well, maybe the index...

Comment: I don't know exactly the situation here... I am very confused...

Comment: is your url like `domain.com/books`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the index method out of the display method like this

```
<?php
   /**
   * @property BooksController $BooksController
   */
    namespace App\Controller;
    use App\Controller\AppController;
    class BooksController extends AppController {
        public function display()
        {
        }
        function index() {
           $this->books->recursive = 1;
           $books = $this->books->find('all');
           $this->set('books', $books);
           $this->render('index');
       }
   }
?>
```

Comment: Cake\ORM\Query Object ( [(help)] => This is a Query object, to get the results execute or iterate it. [sql] => SELECT Books.id AS `Books__id`, Books.isbn AS `Books__isbn`, Books.title AS `Books__title`, Books.description AS `Books__description`, Books.author_id AS `Books__author_id` FROM books Books [params] => Array ( ) [defaultTypes] => Array ( [Books__id] => inte

Comment: I got that after trying your code. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should write your controller code this way

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Controller;
 use App\Controller\AppController;
 class BooksController extends AppController {

 public function index()
 {
    $this->books->recursive = 1;
    $books = $this->books->find('all');
    $this->set('books', $books);
    $this->render('index');
 }
}
```

---

And your view file code is:

```
<table>
<thead>
<th>ISBN</th><th>Title</th><th>Author</th>
</thead>
<?php foreach($books as $key => $book){ ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $book['books']['isbn'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $book['books']['title'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $book['authors']['name'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```